# Seeking geological standard symbol for folding

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, symbology, geology

I'm looking for a symbol for a geological map.

And I can't find it. It's a symbol to represent the folding of the geological layers.

[image]

Comment: Perhaps the [resources provided by the USGS](https://scgeology.github.io/GeMS/index.html) can be helpful for using a standardized symbology for your geologic maps.

Comment: Another ressource : https://www.holcombe.net.au/software/geoqsymbol.html

Comment: And here is one as WKT `POLYGON ((12.44046476961448 -0.8102336939919588, -12.55953523038552 -0.8102336939919588, -12.55953523038552 1.1897663060080412, -0.5595352303856345 1.1897663060080412, -0.5595352303856345 9.189766306008211, -3.5595352303856345 8.189766306007643, -0.0595352303855208 15.18976630600804, 3.4404647696144792 8.189766306007643, 0.4404647696142518 9.189766306008211, 0.4404647696142518 1.1897663060080412, 
    12.44046476961448 1.1897663060080412, 12.44046476961448 -0.8102336939919588))`. Taken from OpenJUMP sources.

Comment: thanks i will do